# Select each distinct value over time without losing NULLs in between

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

Let's assume a table has many columns and a Temporal table is logging its history. There is one field I need to know when it changes.

| Number | VersionStartDate |
| --- | --- |
| 991281 | 2021-11-12 08:27:11 |
| 991281 | 2021-11-12 08:20:11 |
| NULL | 2021-11-12 07:20:11 |
| NULL | 2021-11-12 06:20:11 |
| 771281 | 2021-11-11 08:26:11 |
| NULL | 2021-11-11 08:25:11 |
| 661281 | 2021-11-10 08:24:11 |
| NULL | 2021-11-10 08:22:11 |
| 661281 | 2021-11-10 08:21:11 |
| 551281 | 2021-11-09 08:20:11 |

I need to get each value, and the moment it changed. I also need to know if it's been set NULL so this query is not giving what I need.

```
SELECT
    Number,
    MIN(VersionStartDate) [Date]
FROM _TABLE_ 
GROUP BY
    Number
ORDER BY
    [Date] DESC
```

The result should be

| Number | VersionStartDate |
| --- | --- |
| 991281 | 2021-11-12 08:20:11 |
| NULL | 2021-11-12 06:20:11 |
| 771281 | 2021-11-11 08:26:11 |
| NULL | 2021-11-11 06:25:11 |
| 661281 | 2021-11-10 08:24:11 |
| NULL | 2021-11-10 08:22:11 |
| 661281 | 2021-11-10 08:21:11 |
| 551281 | 2021-11-09 08:20:11 |

Comment: What you have here appears to be a gaps an island problem. `MIN` on it's own won't work.

Comment: Do you want each non-null Number only once?

Comment: @Larnu thanks, knowing how its call will help me find a solution

Comment: @jarlh if there is another value 551281, NULL, 551281, then I want both, if it's following (551281,551281), then I want it distinct

Comment: Add sample data reflecting this, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: @jarlh It's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite similar to JMabee's which appeared after I started working on it, but perhaps a bit simpler:

```
CREATE TABLE #d (Number INT, VersionStartDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO #d(Number, VersionStartDate) 
VALUES
(991281 ,'2021-11-12T08:27:11'),
(991281 ,'2021-11-12T08:20:11'),
(NULL   ,'2021-11-12T07:20:11'),
(NULL   ,'2021-11-12T06:20:11'),
(771281 ,'2021-11-11T08:26:11'),
(NULL   ,'2021-11-11T08:25:11'),
(661281 ,'2021-11-10T08:24:11'),
(NULL   ,'2021-11-10T08:22:11'),
(661281 ,'2021-11-10T08:21:11'),
(551281 ,'2021-11-09T08:20:11');

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  Number,
            VersionStartDate,
            LAG(Number, 1) OVER (ORDER BY VersionStartDate) AS PrevNumber
    FROM    #d
)
SELECT      cte.Number,
            cte.VersionStartDate
FROM        cte
WHERE       ISNULL(cte.Number, -1) <> ISNULL(cte.PrevNumber, -1)
ORDER BY    cte.VersionStartDate DESC;
```

Comment: I prefer your solution because of the use of a CTE instead of subquery

Answer (score 1):

Well this is one way to do it, I am sure there is a more eloquent way to write it, but it gets you started:

```
CREATE TABLE #T(Number int, VersionStartDate datetime)
INSERT INTO #T vALUES
(991281,'2021-11-12 08:27:11'),
(991281,'2021-11-12 08:20:11'),
(NULL,'2021-11-12 07:20:11'),
(NULL,'2021-11-12 06:20:11'),
(771281,'2021-11-11 08:26:11'),
(NULL,'2021-11-11 08:25:11'),
(661281,'2021-11-10 08:24:11'),
(NULL,'2021-11-10 08:22:11'),
(661281,'2021-11-10 08:21:11'),
(551281,'2021-11-09 08:20:11')


SELECT Number, MIN(VersionStartDate) VersionStartDate
FROM
(
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(Number,-1) <> ISNULL(LG,-1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY VersionStartDate desc) GRP
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, LAG(Number,1,-1) OVER(ORDER BY VersionStartDate desc) LG
        FROM #T
    ) X
) Y
GROUP BY GRP,Number
ORDER BY VersionStartDate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Add VersionStartDate in your group by.

```
SELECT
    Number,
    MIN(VersionStartDate)
FROM _TABLE_ 
GROUP BY
    Number, VersionStartDate
ORDER BY
    VersionStartDate DESC
```

Comment: group by versionstartdate will return every row